# information regarding Binutils for bsd cross compilers in linux machine?

Tags: cross-compiling, bsd

i need some information regarding binutils. 1) what doe this do for a cross compilation for BSD ? 2) why does this package needed ? how it helps in making corss compilers for BSD in Linux Ubuntu system?  kindly provide your valuable answers

Comment: What specific problem do you have? What are you trying to achieve, and how is the binutils package failing you?

Comment: am completely new to cross compilers, i am trying to make cross compiler for bsd in linux ubuntu machine.it is not failing for me. but i want to know about binutils what it will do for cross compilers. below commands i am executing.
  
1)     cd binutils-2.21

2) ./configure --enable-libssp --enable-gold --enable-ld --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX

3) Make

4) make check 

5) sudo make install

what does the above commands do? thanks for spending your valuable time on this querry ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you might want to look at how NetBSD builds.  Its build system is portable to almost any POSIX-compatible host, including most any (if not all) GNU/Linux systems.  It first builds a cross-compiler and other tools (including the linker originally from binutils), then uses that to build target system libraries, then it builds all the rest of the system.  However the tools and libraries alone can be used to build anything else to use on a compatible target system.

The paper "[build.sh: Cross-building NetBSD](http://www.mewburn.net/luke/papers/build.sh.pdf)" gives an introduction and overview, and the NetBSD Guide gives detailed instructions.

http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-build.html